# Equivalent of curl's "resolve" option in HTML/Javascript page

Tags: javascript, html, curl, redirect, libcurl

I have an ingress controller that, in order to access certain resources behind it, I need to specify the resource via `curl`'s `--resolve` feature. For example, this request will fail (i.e. not access the endpoint I need):

```
curl http://foo/endpoint
```

However, this request will succeed:

```
curl --resolve foo:80:192.168.100.123  http://foo:80/endpoint
```

In short, I require the equivalent of the `--resolve` feature, but in a simple HTML page instead. The end goal is to just be able to achieve this `--resolve` functionality via a web browser. I've tried various graphical tools such as "RESTer" and other REST client plugins for Firefox, but none of them seem to support this functionality. So, I guess my only remaining option is to write a web page (i.e. HTML) that can accomplish the same thing.

**Question:** how do I craft/issue such a request so I can execute it in a browser, rather than via `curl`? Is this just some HTTP header hackery that I need to implement? I know that trying to do something like setting the `Host` field in the HTTP header doesn't work, so I assume it's more complicated than that.

**Edit:** [it seems the `curl`-specific name for the feature is `CURLOPT_RESOLVE`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent feature in `fetch` or `XHR`.

Hostname resolution cannot be overridden. You can't even make a request directly to an IP address and override the `Host` request header because it is marked as a [forbidden header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#terminology-headers).

---

The closest you could come would be to write a proxy (using server-side code) and then make the request from the browser to the proxy.